# Word for something partitioned into 16 parts?

Tags: single-word-requests, mathematics

On a two-dimensional Cartesian plane we can naturally subdivide the space into four **quadrants** at the origin. In three-dimensions, the partition into eight parts are known as **octants**. In four-dimensional space we have sixteen parts; what is the corresponding name for each partition?

Wikipedia has an [n-dimensional name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthant):

> In geometry, an **orthant** or **hyperoctant** is the analogue in n-dimensional Euclidean space of a quadrant in the plane or an octant in three dimensions.

Even if it isn't common usage, what would the next term be for 4-dimensions (of sixteen parts)?

Comment: In heraldry, it's called [_Seize Quartiers_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seize_Quartiers). But that only refers to having inherited 16 coats of arms, each from an armigerous ancestor -- basically it means all 16 of one's great-great-grandparents had arms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Latin for *sixteen* is *sedecim*, so one could coin the term ***sedecimant*** for the 16 orthants of four-dimensional space.

Comment: Could there possibly be an alternate spelling of that? Googling the word gives exactly two results, this post and another on Math SE where a comment posits the exact same thing: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/434503/196

Comment: That's because there isn't a word; it's coined specially. Nice to know that I came up with the same word as a mathematician though.

Comment: I asked since I don't know how Latin modifies the prefix, e.g. eight -> octo but eight+"sections" -> "octant", so does sixteen+"sections" still read as sedecim+"ant"?

Comment: The *-ant* needs to be immediately preceded by a consonant, and *sedecim* conveniently provides one. If the suffix were *-pant*, the sequence would likely be *quadrapant, octopant, sedecipant.*